# collectionView can't reloadItemsAtIndexPaths at current scene

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

First, I create a collection view controller with a storyboard, and subclass a cell (called `RouteCardCell`).

The cell lazy loads an image from Web. To accomplish this, I create a thread to load the image. After the image loads, I call the method `reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:` to display the image.

Loading the image works correctly, but there's a problem displaying the image. My cells display the new image only after scrolling them off-screen and back on.

Why don't my images display properly after reloading the item?

Here's the relevant code:

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as RouteCardCell
    let road = currentRoads[indexPath.item]
    cell.setText(road.title)

    var imageData = self.imageCache.objectForKey(NSString(format: "%d", indexPath.item)) as? NSData
    if let imageData_ = imageData{
        cell.setImage(UIImage(data: imageData_))
    }
    else{
        cell.setImage(nil)
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), { () -> Void in
            var Data = self.getImageFromModel(road, index:indexPath.item)
            if let Data_ = Data{
                self.imageCache.setObject(Data_, forKey: NSString(format: "%d", indexPath.item))
                NSLog("Download Image for %d", indexPath.item)
            }
            else{
                println("nil Image")
            }
        })
        self.reloadCollectionViewDataAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    }
    return cell
}

func reloadCollectionViewDataAtIndexPath(indexPath:NSIndexPath){
    var indexArray = NSArray(object: indexPath)

    self.collectionView!.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths(indexArray)
}

func getImageFromModel(road:Road, index:Int)->NSData?{
    var images = self.PickTheData!.pickRoadImage(road.roadId)
    var image: Road_Image? = images.firstObject as? Road_Image

    if let img = image{
        return img.image
    }
    else{
        return nil
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `reloadCollectionViewDataAtIndexPath(indexPath)` before the image is done downloading. Instead of calling it outside of your `dispatch_async` block, add another block to go back on the main queue once it's done.

For example:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), { () -> Void in
    // download the image…

    // got the image, now update the UI
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.reloadCollectionViewDataAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    }
})
```

This is a pretty tough problem in iOS development. There are other cases you haven't handled, like what happens if the user is scrolling really quickly and you end up with a bunch of downloads that the user doesn't even need to see. You may want to try using a library like [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) instead, which has many improvements over your current implementation.

Comment: thanks! problem solved.And thank you for your advice:)And for correcting the question description^_^